# Closure of a Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group.

Suppose $H$ is an open subgroup of $G$ which is itself a Lie group.

Need the closure of $H$ in $G$ also be a Lie group?

**Edit:** Due to another issue being resolved, this question is no longer pressing.  But the answer seems unlikely to be yes, at least, in the way I had hoped.